# How do you sign a request API (when it's you who decide how to do it)?

Tags: api, digital-signature

Actually I'm making an API for our webservices. For time and resources reason we can't use oauth now. It's planned for future version but for now we need to do in other way.

@romainmuller showed me a nice client <-> server exchange scheme and for this one I need to sign my request with secret API and session token. My question is this, is there any standard for signature generation? I think to do something like this:

1. Sort arguments.
2. Make a string : `HTTPMETHOD&NORMALISEURL&NORMALIZEPARAMS&SECRET&TOKEN` where normalize stuff is just a utf8_encode followed by a url_encode
3. Use HMAC/SHA256 with API secret on this string.

But with this process I never know wjich API client call me. I need API key or session token reading to know that. How might I implement it in this process?

Comment: i dont understand the idea that you're going to be faster at coming up with your own secure mechanism faster than deploying an established standard for which tons of articles and 3rd party libraries exist

Comment: We got some technical contrainst like a sysadmin who didn't want to upgrade our servers or install / activate server component ... so implementing oauth was pretty hard to do right now.